# Function of なんて in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The following excerpt is from a scene from Sword Art Online, where Kirito and Asuna are discussing whether or not the killer they are pursuing is a ghost or not. Asuna seems to think it is, but Kirito is unconvinced (because the killer had used a teleporting crystal). Kirito says:

> いや、そんなことは絶対にない。そもそも幽霊だったらさっきも転移結晶**なんて**使わないで

I'm going to take a guess that the なん (a more emphatic version of なの?) is providing the secondary information for his explanation (the "ghost" used a teleport crystal), and the て is the quotative particle (usually って but て because it's following ん?). Or is て loosely connecting the first clause with the second clause?

I could understand what he was saying in this sentence, but I really don't understand the grammar here or how it is operating structurally :( I would really like to know!

Comment: Did you check a dictionary for なんて? [Jisho entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6)

Comment: Thanks for that, but is なんて really expressing disdain/dislike in this instance?

Comment: I wouldn't say "disdain/dislike" in this case, but it also lists "astonishment, etc" in the entry. Basically, it means "some strong feeling" is associated with what precedes it, not necessarily disdain or dislike.